# Tap Gesture on UIView as SubView get BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, subview

I have an from UIViewController derived Class named AdminViewController.

I want to enable singleTab Recognizer to this View.

The View is Called in an the MainViewController with:

```
AdminViewController* AdminViewC = [[AdminViewController alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:AdminViewC.view];
```

In the AdminViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        [gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedGestureAction:)];
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)tappedGestureAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap{
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"View Tapped" message:@"Tapped" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dissmiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
    [av show];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(500, -200, 200, 300)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.view action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}
```

If i Touch the View in my MainViewController i get this:

*'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView handleSingleTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x296d50'*

has someone a hint?
regards, phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added your gesture on `self.view`, but you did not implement single tap selector:

```
-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGesture
{
}
```